# Getting Apache to serve sites on LAN

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I'm connected to the LAN in my university with an ip address of `172.16.123.12`. I'm trying to deploy a flask application on an apache server so that the entire campus can see the website. I've successfully deployed the app using mod_wsgi but I cant get to work on the LAN. It's working fine on `localhost/flask` but I can't myself access the site on `http://127.0.1.1/flask` or `http://172.16.123.12/flask` but the "It works" apache page is accessible from both `http://127.0.1.1` and `http://172.16.123.12`

Here is my virtualhosts conf for the flask site -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    WSGIDaemonProcess flask_test threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias /flask /var/www/flask_test/flask.wsgi
    ErrorLog "/var/www/flask_test/error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/www/flask_test/access.log" combined

    <Directory /var/www/flask_test>
        WSGIProcessGroup flask_test
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 Linux
```

I tried changing the ServerName to my ipaddress as well but to no avail. Can someone please let me know where I am going wrong? Thanks a ton!

Output from apapch2ctl -S

```
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost Linux (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/flasktest:1)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: Can you provide the output from `apache2ctl -S` or `apachectl -S`, as the case may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ServerName`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername) `localhost` means that your app can be accessible only when requesting via the `localhost` domain.

Delete the `ServerName` line and move your config to the outside of the [`VirtualHost`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) section, then try again.

- **`/etc/httpd/conf.d/flask.conf`** (Red Hat based)
- **`/etc/apache2/conf.d/flask.conf`** (Debian based)

  ```
  WSGIDaemonProcess flask_test threads=5
  WSGIScriptAlias /flask /var/www/flask_test/flask.wsgi

  <Directory /var/www/flask_test>
      WSGIProcessGroup flask_test
      WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
  </Directory>
  ```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks a ton! Tutorials around the web suggested to use a virtualhost configuration. When should use a virtualhost config and when should I add a conf file in conf.d? Will this method work if I do this on the production server as well? Thanks a ton!

Comment: You can use virtualhost config if your servername can be resolvable in LAN. For e.g: setup a local DNS, go to 172.16.123.x machine, do a `nslookup your.domain.com` will resolve to the 172.16.123.12. Do you have any domain maps to your production server's IP?

Comment: nslookup <production server ip> returns none. So I'm guessing I need to proceed the same way there also.